# Symfony Twig and for loop

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, twig

I have the following problem. I have a meeting table in the database, including `id`, `guest`, `host`, `start_time`, `end_time` and `table_number`. I use wkhtmltopdf and symfony 3 to generate, the mere generation of pdf is no problem, unfortunately Twig does not want to cooperate with me. I would like to do it first to generate meetings for table 1, then for 2 etc. The whole process should look like this:

- Beginning of generating pdf for table 1
- The table changes from 1 to 2, a page break occurs and starts generating a new page with meetings for table 2, etc.

The problem is that it generates me a pdf for table 1, then adds one meeting for table 2. It starts to generate a pdf for table 2, at the end throws me 1 meeting from table 3. The generated pdf looks like this: http://cyrklaf.eu/table.pdf

I have no idea where the error is, that he always gets one meeting from another table. My Twig code because the problem lies in it:

My Twig code:

```
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            background: #FFF;
        }

        .page {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
{% set last_table = 1 %}
{% for meeting in meetings %}
    <div class="page">
    {{ meeting.guest }} {{ meeting.host }} stolik obecny {{ meeting.tableNumber }} stolik poprzedni {{ last_table }}

    {% if meeting.tableNumber != last_table %} // 
        {% set last_table = meeting.tableNumber %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle table break in following manner:

```
{% set previous_table_number = 1 %}
{% for meeting in meetings %}
    {# This handle table break close old div if is changed #}
    {% if meeting.tableNumber != previous_table_number and not loop.first %} 
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    {# This handle table break #}
    {% if meeting.tableNumber != previous_table_number or loop.first %} 
      <div class="page">
    {% endif %}

    {{ meeting.guest }} {{ meeting.host }} stolik obecny {{ meeting.tableNumber }} stolik poprzedni {{ previous_table_number }}

    {% if loop.last %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}


{% set previous_table_number = meeting.tableNumber %}


{% endfor %}
```

You can play with it in [this working fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/wyeppy)

Hope this help

Comment: everything works now, the only problem is that it generates a blank page at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like that in Twig:

```
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            background: #FFF;
        }

        .page {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
{% for i in 1..4 %}
  {% for meeting in meetings %}
    {% if meeting.tableNumber == i %}

      <div class="page">
        {{ meeting.guest }} {{ meeting.host }} stolik obecny {{ meeting.tableNumber }} stolik poprzedni {{ last_table }}
      </div>

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The number of tables is not fixed, sometimes it can be max 20, another time 5, so the for loop drops out, unless I will pass in the parameters how many tables there are. On the other hand, I can have eg 10 tables, but for example 2 of them will be for other purposes, and the for loop will not pass the exam.